# Error opening Apps like WhatsApp to share text: Flutter

Tags: flutter, url, android-intent, whatsapp, app-launcher

I am trying to open apps like WhatsApp, Twitter and Facebook from inside my flutter app but I get a URL scheme error. Please help!
The code I am using is

```
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () async {
                          String url =
                              "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=Hello there!";
                          var encoded = Uri.encodeFull(url);
                          Uri whatsAppUri = Uri.parse(encoded);
                          if (await canLaunchUrl(whatsAppUri)) {
                            await launchUrl(whatsAppUri);
                          }
                        },
```

I get the following error screen-
[image: Error screen when button is pressed]

Please help me find the correct method and URL. Also please help me with Twitter and Facebook as I need to use them as well. Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code:

```
String url() {
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      return "https://wa.me/$phone/?text=Hello there!";
    } else {
      return "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=$phone=Hello there!}";
    }
  }

String url = url();
var encoded = Uri.encodeFull(url);
                          Uri whatsAppUri = Uri.parse(encoded);
                          if (await canLaunchUrl(whatsAppUri)) {
                            await launchUrl(whatsAppUri);
                          }
```

In the place of $phone you can write phone number of user to which you want to send.

Comment: I don't want to provide a number from within the app.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
const url = "whatsapp://send?text=Hello World!"
```

or

```
const url = "https://wa.me/?text=Hello World!";
```

and add this to your `info.plist` if your using ios:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>whatsapp</string>
</array>
```

for facebook:

```
const url = "fb://facewebmodal/f?href=$username";
```

for twitter:

```
const url = "https://twitter.com/username";
```

last but not least make sure you add configuration right like:

```
<intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <data android:scheme="https" />
</intent>

<intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
</intent>
```

you can find more information from [here](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher)

Comment: For Android, I cannot open WhatsApp with the URLs mentioned above. Getting message like    I/chromium(28471): [INFO:CONSOLE(29)] "Refused to load the font 'https://static.whatsapp.net/rsrc.php/yH/r/c_1vdG88uNh.woff2' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "font-src data: https://*.fbcdn.net". Also getting the same screen as above

Comment: are adding android configuration that package said? because the second one is opening in my android device.

Comment: can you please specify it, package only have for phone and SMS I guess.

Comment: I will check with this again. Thank You!